# Can someone help explain the specifics of why a DBA would be against database clustering?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2016, clustering, corruption

I'm a system admin and do not manage databases on a daily basis. My organization is considering database clustering to practically eliminate downtime for certain services. We use mostly oracle databases (v19), and some SQL (2016). Our DBA's are against this, and from what I'm researching the only real negative to database clustering is a low risk of database corruption. We have four different backup locations, including an off-site backup. I'm trying to further understand our DBAs stance, and get a grasp on how database clustering would impact their daily work. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried asking your DBAs?

Comment: Yes. The answer I received is that they're worried about database corruption and it makes their job more difficult. I've not been given any specifics about this, which is why I'm trying to get outside opinions.

Comment: Well, it does of course make their jobs more difficult. As for the database corruption, either they are incompetent or they simply try to scare you into abandoning your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as a DBA with 30 years experience with Oracle, and about half of that with Oracle RAC, I can say that if your goal is reduced downtime, then RAC (active-active clustering with shared storage) or DataGuard (replication with failover) can certainly help with that. The downside is that they *can* introduce a lot of complexity and - for RAC - some specific hardware requirements: so a significant learning curve if your DBA's haven't used these technologies before, and possibly some expense to get the right hardware to make it work.

In my experience, the risk of data corruption isn't significantly greater with RAC or DataGuard. I've actually never heard that as a "con" with current Oracle disaster recovery technologies; Fortune 100 companies rely heavily on these on a daily basis, so I'd be inclined to trust it as long as your DBAs are properly trained.

From a purely business perspective, RAC *does* introduce significant additional license costs. DataGuard is less complex than RAC, and the basic version doesn't require any additional licensing. Oracle also has a product named GoldenGate that can be used to provide DR for lots of other DB platforms in addition to Oracle.

In the end, you need to weigh all of those expenses (training, hardware, licenses, etc.) and risks against the cost of downtime and/or whatever disaster recovery plan you have now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the what the Oracle answers mentioned, you run into similar hurdles with SQL Servers too. The defacto solution for HA/DR in SQL Server is setting up failover clusters via [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). But the potential hurdles of using them are:

1. Increased licensing costs - All servers need to be running Enterprise edition, and secondary replica servers need to be licensed.
2. Increased performance overhead - As the data is synchronized from the primary to the secondaries. If you run one of the secondaries in synchronous mode (to minimize the risk of data loss) then it is possible for that secondary to be a bottleneck to the primary server when it gets too far behind and the primary is waiting on the transactions to be replayed on that secondary.
3. Increased work to manage - Things like database and server updates become no longer trivial. There is a process where you essentially must break the cluster and cause a failover to one server to apply the updates first, then failover back to the other server to do the same, and then re-enable the cluster. Verifying that the AlwaysOn Availability Groups are still working as expected and that all of the secondaries are caught up to the primary is a process as well. And from an application perspective, you'll likely have to make at least some minor changes to ensure the applications know which server to connect to appropriately. (AlwaysOn Availability Groups have a Listener that can be leveraged to make this easier.)

There's a pretty decent sized learning curve to using AlwaysOn Availability Groups, both for the infrastructure team managing the failover cluster and the DBA team managing the actual replicas. Aside from all of that, I'm sure there's other reasons it's not so turnkey to implement either. Alternatively, there are HA/DR solutions out there that infrastructure teams use which work by maintaining an exact replica of the entire server itself. I've heard these minify some of the aforementioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Oracle Dataguard and Oracle RAC (especially) it adds additional complexity. Like a lot of complexity(dedicated VLAN for interconnect, FibreChannel shared storage, several IP addresses, you need root access to DB server in order to manage RAC cluster, ...).

- RAC in rare cases it might cause more problems that it solves. Especially older RAC versions did not have good reputation.
- There can be RAC specific performance problems. Also quite rare.
- All Oracle's clustering solutions require at least minimal cooperation of application side. If you can not adjust configuration on client's side, clustering solution is just a waste of money.
- RAC cluster will not help you with accidental data corruption anyway. If you truncate a table, then data is gone on all nodes. DataGuard with standby DB in flashback mode can help you get lost data quite fast.
- DadaGuard implies at least minimal downtime during patching(5-10 minutes lets say). On RAC you can have zero-downtime patching, but you need cooperation on application server side.

IHMO you should 1st ask yourself when kind of error/incident/issue you do want to prevent.

Comment: Current RAC versions (anything since 11gR2 at least, and certainly anything currently under support from Oracle) are quite stable. The biggest issue with client/app compatibility is the ability to reconnect to the database automatically if there's a failover event. If your app can do that, then most other things will work themselves out.